# Unable to get UniqueIdentifier from X500Principal of X509Certificate

Tags: java, cryptography, certificate, digital-signature, x509certificate

I wanted to get the unique identifier of a X509Certificate using Java.

I tried to get the value from using the below code:-

```
java.security.cert.X509Certificate certificate=// certificate object
certificate.getSubjectX500Principal().getName();
```

But i am unable to get the unique identifier value alone.This is the value i am getting:-

```
2.5.4.45=#0309000000db000000a01a,OU=06
```

I wanted to get the value alone for "2.5.4.45".

I also tried to get the value using the below code:-

```
        String dn2 = certificate.getSubjectX500Principal().getName();
        LdapName ldapDN;
        ldapDN = new LdapName(dn2);

        for(Rdn rdn: ldapDN.getRdns()) {
            System.out.println(rdn.getType() + " -> " + rdn.getValue());                
            if(rdn.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("2.5.4.45")){
               System.out.println(rdn.getValue());
            }
```

I am getting an object as the value for unique identifier. I am not able to parse the Object, get the value for this.

**Update ::**
I am still not able to figure out a way to get the UniqueIdentifier  identifer.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: kind of hard to help here - can you provide the problem certificate - so we can see what is going on? first suspicion is a malformed Principal String.

Answer (score 2):

You need provide set of known OIDs. Then you will get a human readable value of DN String. Value of known OIDs will be readable when you define OID. For example:

```
    Map<String, String> knownOids = new HashMap<String, String>();
    knownOids.put("2.5.4.45", "uniqueIdentifier");
    String humanReadableDN = certToken.getCertificate().getSubjectX500Principal().getName(X500Principal.RFC2253, knownOids);
```

Example OID repository you can find here: http://oid-info.com/get/2.5.4.45

For Example, this:

```
CN=Krzysiek,1.2.840.113549.1.9.1=#160f3334353334354064666766642e706c
```

Will be translated to this:

```
commonName=Krzysiek,emailAddress=345345@dfgfd.pl
```

When you provide a set with:

```
knownOids.put("1.2.840.113549.1.9.1", "emailAddress");
```